# If item within list in pandas column is a dictionary key, replace with value, if not in dictionary, delete

Tags: python, pandas

If a pandas column contains a list, you can use a dictionary to convert all the values using

```
df['listColumn'] = df['listColumn'].apply(lambda x: [columnDictionary[i] for i in x])
```

However, there are instances where not all the items in a list are keys to the dictionary. In that case, how do you replace those items with nothing.

For example

```
columnDictionary = {a:1, b:2, d:7, f:8 }
```

Specific Pandas row/column: [ a, b, c, d, e]

Specific Pandas row/column after conversion: [ 1, 2, 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple condition to check if a list value is in target dict keys list:

```
In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame({'listColumn': ['a', 123, list('abcde')]})                                           

In [48]: repl_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':7, 'f':8 }                                                              

In [49]: df['listColumn'].apply(lambda x: [repl_dict[v] for v in x if v in repl_dict] if isinstance(x, list) else x)                                                                                                   
Out[49]: 
0            a
1          123
2    [1, 2, 7]
Name: listColumn, dtype: object
```

Comment: I switched the answer to this one. The other one was easier to read, but I noticed that it takes a long time to run, and eats up all my ram, where as your answer takes a sec to run, and doesn't eat up ram. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2):

Use "if else" inside the lamdba function :

Method 1: apply lambda on columns, below on one column only ( axis = 0 )

```
# apply lambda on 1 column (axis = 0) 
d = {'col1':[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

columnDictionary ={'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':7, 'f':8 } 

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [columnDictionary[x] if x in columnDictionary else ''])
df
```

Method 2: apply lambda on rows (axis = 1), row by row (I think it is slower)

```
d = {'col1':[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

columnDictionary ={'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':7, 'f':8 } 

df['listColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: [columnDictionary[i] if i in columnDictionary else '' for i in x],axis=1)
df
```

Result :

```
    col1    listColumn
0   a   [1]
1   b   [2]
2   c   []
3   d   [7]
4   e   []
```

Comment: Although this is easier to read, somehow this eats up all the ram in my system and takes a while for it to complete operation, where as the other solution takes a few seconds, low ram

Comment: @SantoshGupta7, I edited my answer and added another method that will apply Lambda on columns instead of rows. I guess it will be faster. I will check the performance and let you know if I find something else.

Answer (score 1):

There is a build-in function to check if something is list, it called **isinstance(mydata, list)** whitch will return True or False respectivelly.